# WebStorm: Cannot find runner

Tags: webstorm

I'm porting a run configuration from VS Code.  It's a compound configuration consisting of two run configurations:

1. Attach to Node.js/Chrome
2. Node.js

If I debug those two configurations in either order I can debug my app.  If I create a compound configuration it will throw an error:

> Error running 'Attach to Renderer': Cannot find runner for Attach to
>   Renderer

which refers to the Chrome configuration.

Any reason why the compound wouldn't work?

Comment: what are you trying to debug - server-side code or client part (executed in browser)?  Do you have any special reason for using *Attach to Node.js/Chrome* configuration? It's supposed to be used for attaching to remote Node.js process - but you are using *Node.js* run configuration at the same time, so the Node process is being run locally?

Comment: Forgive me since I'm new to node, but our workflow was to start a live reload server `ng serve -e electron --app desktop`.  Then run the compound config described.  The chrome debugger was necessary to debug, possibly related to the way the electron server works?  Going one-by-one the node config starts the app, however it can't be debugged without the attach config.

Comment: I see; it's used for render process debugging. Should work in WebStorm as well. Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/ for some info on debugging electron in WebStorm